# Is there a Gfortran flag similar to intel ifort's -ipo-c, that would generate single optimized object from all compiled files?

Tags: fortran, compiler-optimization, gfortran, intel-fortran

Intel Fortran compiler/linker has the optional flag `-ipo-c` or `/Qipo-c` which enables the generation of a single interprocedurally-optimized object file from all files, which can be later used for linking. Is there an equivalent flag to Intel's `-ipo-c`in gfortran?

Answer (score 3):

GCC has `-fwhole-program`, does that work for `gfortran`?

Or if you don't want to pass all the Fortran source files on one giant command line, there's `-flto` link-time optimization which uses a linker "plugin" to run the optimizer on GIMPLE stored in `.o` files (instead of or as well as machine code).

LTO means you should pass all your optimization options to the invocation of `gfortran` that does the linking, as well as the `gfortran -c` that compiles to `.o`.

So you might use `gfortran -ffast-math -O3 -march=native -flto` to compile and link, assuming `gfortran` supports the same options as `gcc`.  (And that `-march=native` is what you want: make an executable optimized for the computer you compiled on, which might SIGILL on other computers without all the ISA extensions this one supports.)

Comment: IIRC, there are only  a few optimizations done specifically in the Fortran frontend, most are done in the common GCC middle-end and backend. All the options you have mentioned are applicale to gfortran.